# TLP charge thresholds (Non Thinkpad)

Tags: power-management, laptop, lenovo, battery

Hey guys how are you?

My question about TLP charge thresholds in Ubuntu Linux 17.04.

I have Lenovo Z51-70 in windows it had its utility that stop charging at 60% so the laptop can get energy from AC adapter now in Linux can I use thresholds in non ThinkPad?  Although my laptop support this, and how to properly do it so it can hold at 60% then continue when I am done, sorry but I find the official site so complicated cause English isn't my native language and I'm new in Linux :)

Excuse my grammar

Comment: What "official site"? Is there a link?

Comment: http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, ...and it says this: "Please note: TLP runs on every laptop brand. Setting the battery charge thresholds is available for IBM/Lenovo ThinkPads only." So, if you do not have a Thinkpad, it probably will not work.

Comment: yeah, Unfortunately, I read that line but thought someone figured some ways to make it work. Thanks for the help appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Support for what is now called 'conservation mode' (ie: limiting the battery charge range to 55-60%) has been baked into Linux for Lenovo Ideapad laptops since version 4.4.

Enable it with:

```
sudo bash -c "echo 1 >/sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode"
```

Disable it with:

```
sudo bash -c "echo 0 >/sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode"
```

Or use [this](https://github.com/schinfo/lenopow) nice helper script where conservation mode can be enabled with:

```
lenopow -e
```

and disabled with:

```
lenopow -d
```